# Ubuntu Qt link boost log

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, boost

I try to link the `boost 1.55 log library` with a `Qt` `*.pro` file.

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$system(echo ${BOOST_INCLUDE_DIR}) 

LIBS += -L$$system(echo ${BOOST_LIB_DIR}) 
LIBS += -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lboost_thread -lboost_log
```

I get a reference error with boost log , because I didn't define

```
-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK
```

Can anyone tell me how to define this inside the `*.pro` file?

In my `CMake` file i can use: `ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK)`

What is the corresponding command in `qmake`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DEFINES`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#defines):

```
DEFINES += BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought i tried it, but it is possible that i didn't use clean before